# When can enemies not see a soldier on a roof?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I'm playing I/I and this is something that I can't completely figure out. When a unit is on the roof of a building units one story below it sometimes can't see it, but when the unit is simply on elevated ground enemy units can spot it without trouble.

There are however some edge cases (all questions regard units that do not stand on edge of roofs/elevated ground):

- it seems that units two or more stories below unit on elevated ground at least sometimes can't see it. Is there some known rule to figure it out when unit can be seen?
- if unit A is on roof on level 1 (counting levels from level 0 - ground level) and enemy unit is on roof on level 2 can unit A see unit B?
- what about elevated ground? If unit A is on elevated ground on level 1 and unit B is on roof on level 2 can unit A see unit B?
- is roof of UFO considered elevated ground or roof?
- or does it depend on distance from unit on roof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simply based on line of sight, which depends on a variety of factors. These include distance from the roof; objects between unit on ground and the roof; height of the roof...